# Number of ring homomorphisms form $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have tried :

Let $f$ be an homomorphism  form $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z_{12}$. we have to find the possible image of $1$ and $x$. Suppose $f(1) = a$, then $f(1)^2 = f(1) = a^2 = a$, then the possible value of $a = 0,4 , 9$,
if $f(1) = 0$, then $f = 0$

How to find the image of $x$.

Please help me how to proceed further.

Thank you

Comment: Are your ring homomorphisms supposed to send $1$s to $1$s? If so, $x$ can go to anything.

Comment: $x$ is restricted if $1$ does not go to $1$ because we must have $f(1x)=f(x)$. @whacka

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah, that's a good point.

Comment: @ Whacka : definitely $1 $ send to $1$., you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1$ goes to $1$, we can invoke the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the free commutative ring with unity on the set $\{x\}$ and note that $x$ can be sent to anything. Thus there are $12$ possible homomorphisms with $1$ sent to $1$.

There exist homomorphisms where $1$ does not go to $1$. The important thing is that $f(1)f(x)=f(x)$. If $f(1)=0$, then $f(x)=0$. If $f(1)=4$, we could have $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=4$ or $f(x)=8$. If $f(1)=9$, then we could have $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=3$, $f(x)=6$, or $f(x)=9$, thus there are $8$ additional possible homomorphisms. (If I calculated incorrectly you can sue me; in any case the procedure was to find all values $y$ such that $f(1)y=y$).

Comment: @ Matt : How can you say that $1$  must go to $1$

Comment: @Struggler Perhaps I misunderstood, I thought that you said that $1$ had to go to $1$. If not I need to change my answer.

Comment: @ Matt ): Can this result be generalized for $\mathbb Z_n$ instead of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ ?

Comment: @Struggler I edited to include the non-unital homomorphisms, but it's late and I'm tired so you should check my work.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 If $1$ is sent to $1$ then the generalization is simple, $x$ can go to anything so there are $n$ homomorphisms. For non-unital homomorphisms I have no idea, I haven't really thought about it. For this one I did it by brute force.